# How to show return values fom a PHP XML-RPC call?

Tags: php, xml-rpc

I can't seem to find any code to display returned values from the call.

I am running the xml-lib from the software vendor at the following link

https://support.sippysoft.com/support/solutions/articles/3000013653-xml-rpc-api-sign-up-html-page-fresh-version-

```
<?php

include 'xmlrpc/xmlrpc.inc';


function listAccounts()
{
   //$params = array(new xmlrpcval(array("i_account"=> new xmlrpcval('14719', "string")), 'struct'));

    $msg = new xmlrpcmsg('listAccounts');

    /* replace here URL  and credentials to access to the API */
    $cli = new xmlrpc_client('https://DOMAINHERE/xmlapi/xmlapi');
    $cli->setSSLVerifyPeer(false);
    $cli->setSSLVerifyHost(false);
    $cli->setCredentials('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', CURLAUTH_DIGEST);

    $r = $cli->send($msg, 20);
    if ($r->faultCode()) {
      error_log("Fault. Code: " . $r->faultCode() . ", Reason: " . $r->faultString());
      print_r ($r->faultString());
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
    return $r->value();

    // I need something here to write returned values to normal PHP variable

    }
}
```

Comment: You're getting downvoted for a couple of reasons - A.) You're yelling and 2.) there is no actual question in your question.

Comment: My appologies.. Edited Post

Comment: I expect the values from the XML-RPC call are in `$r->value()`. The documentation should tell you what type that is - a string? an object? You can do `echo gettype($r->value()); exit();` temporarily, prior to the return, to see what type it is.

Comment: Hi .. Thanks for the reply it returns object when I use your code..

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to the comment from halfer.

I managed to get the issue and digging through the code in the library I found a function that does the trick.

Thanks a million for your pointer it really helped.

I am new to php and xml and the learning curve is quite tall but thanks.

for someone else reference maybe in the future here is the corrected code with the last 2 lines that does the magic for me.

```
<?php
include 'xmlrpc/xmlrpc.inc';


        // $params = array(new xmlrpcval(array("offset"=> new xmlrpcval("1", "int")
        //                                ,"i_customer"=> new xmlrpcval("321", "int")
        //                                 ), 'struct'));

       $params = array(new xmlrpcval(array("i_customer"=> new xmlrpcval("321", "int")

                                           ), 'struct'));

       $msg = new xmlrpcmsg('listAccounts', $params);

       /* replace here URL  and credentials to access to the API */
       $cli = new xmlrpc_client('DOMAIN');
       $cli->setSSLVerifyPeer(false);
       $cli->setdebug(0);
       $r = $cli->send($msg, 20);       /* 20 seconds timeout */

       if ($r->faultCode()) {
         error_log("Fault. Code: " . $r->faultCode() . ", Reason: " . $r->faultString());
         echo $r->faultString();
       }

       // now lets decode the xml response..
        $values=php_xmlrpc_decode($r->value());
        var_dump ($values['accounts'][0][username]);

?>
```

Comment: Please mark your question as the answer (green checkmark) if it answered your question. That will help future users.